# displaying session value instead of code itself in aspx

Tags: asp.net, session

```
<%= Session.Item("user_fullname")%>
```

this supposed to display session value right?
but mine is displaying code itself....

Note: I have included aspx page in another aspx, like:

```
<%   Response.WriteFile("../etc/header1.aspx") %>
```

the displaing session code is inside header1.aspx

anyone knows how to display session value?

Comment: What is your Response.ContentType in this case ?

Comment: I am just using Response.WriteFile("../etc/header1.aspx") in html codes, i am not sure what content type is

Comment: Try with set content type to  "text/html".

Answer (score 0):

Session items would be stored as an `Object`.  You need to cast to the correct type:

```
<%= (string)Session.Item("user_fullname") %>
```

Comment: why to use `.ToString()`??

Comment: it is displaying <%= (string)Session.Item("user_fullname") %> itself, not the value of session

Comment: Hrm.  This is definitely WebForms and not MVC?

Answer (score 0):

When using `Response.WriteFile("../etc/header1.aspx")`, the usual Page Life cycle will NOT be executed for the mentioned `header1.aspx` page.

Since there will be no asp.net page life cycle processing , the inline code 
`<% %>`  won't be executed at all and therefore all such statements will be displayed as it is.

`Response.WriteFile()` is used to write just the Contents of a file, which can contain HTML , Controls,  directly to the output stream.